# Preserving folder structure with vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, build, vite

I have a photography portfolio website with a lot of photos, my source folder structure is like this

```
Collections
├───Collection1
│   └───Album1
│   │   ├───Photo1
│   │   ├───Photo2
│   │   ├───Photo3
│   │   ├───index.ts (album index)
│   ├───Album2
│   │   ├───Photo4
│   │   ├───Photo5
│   │   ├───Photo6
│   │   ├───index.ts
│   index.ts (collection index)
├───Collection2
│   └───Album1
│   │   ├───Photo7
│   │   ├───Photo8
│   │   ├───Photo9
│   │   ├───index.ts
│   index.ts
index.ts (main index)
```

The index files have metadata about the photos that's generated with a custom script. The main index also collects thumbnails and favourites.

When I build the code, it's output like this

```
build
└───assets
│   ├───Photo1-6d00032f
│   ├───Photo2-bb33a10f
│   ├───Photo3-46d0451f
│   ├───Photo4-729ae12e
...
│   index.js-2e2a76a
```

This means whenever I want to add photos, I basically have to reupload all of the photos, which upwards of 20GB at this point. I was wondering if there was any way to preserve the folder structure for the photos. Then when I want to upload more, I just add the photos and replace the index file.

I know this is not the ideal way to do it, but it's for me it was the ideal balance between cost, performance and complexity. I just want to know if this is an unavoidable downside or if I can do anything about it.

Comment: "I basically have to reupload all of the photos" Do you mean when deploying? Why is that? The already uploaded photo names shouldn't change, so you should be able to just upload the new ones.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put all these assets into your public directory.
This way they will not be treated as part of your code.

See : https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#the-public-directory

The filenames of code get hashes attached for cache busting. So a proxy won't serve stale scripts when you release.